# Titanium JS: With Titanium Alloy, can the database be viewed?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I'm getting used to using Titanium Alloy to build apps and I've added some model JS files and created some of those models using the `Alloy.createModel` method, and then saved them using the `.save()` method.

The only thing I can't work out is, where is this database and how can I view it and inspect the tables? Can I use a database browser such as Sequal Pro to view it?

EDIT: I'd like to view the database that I'm testing with on my emulator. Viewing a database from an iPhone would also be great.

Comment: Using iOS or android?

Comment: iOS at the moment, but Android later. I'd mostly like to view it locally on my machine thought, while I develop and test with the emulator.

Comment: how about in android sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find the sqlite database file in the iPhone Simulator support files:

> ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[OS version]/Applications/[appGUID]/

And then go to private documents.

Copy it do desired folder and then use with sqlite manager or similar :)

Thanks

Comment: Do I have to do this every time the database is updated? And how do I know which GUID is the correct one?

Comment: You could guess by app name and yes you have to do each time or import the sqlite from thath folder itself and you would be good to go

Comment: Inside `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[OS version]/Applications/` are about 6 GUID's, how can I tell which is which?

Comment: Go to each folder you would find each name of app